# How to call a mvsc dll (C++ or Rust) from Progress Open Edge

Tags: c++, windows, rust, openedge, progress-db

I have a dll that i want to call from Progress code but I can't complete.

I have tried with Visual Studio 2022, Windows C++ Dll and Rust Dll.

**Windows C++, Visual Studio 2022 with Progress**

```
Cpp
```

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdreason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    return 1;
}
*/

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int HelloWorld(int hello)
{
    return hello * 2;
}
```

```
Progress
```

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

PROCEDURE HelloWorld EXTERNAL "C:\Users\Steee\source\repos\DllHelloWorld\x64\Release\DllHelloWorld.dll" CDECL:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER hello AS SHORT NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER rCode AS SHORT NO-UNDO.
END.

DEFINE VARIABLE hello AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE rCode AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
hello = 3.

RUN HelloWorld(hello, OUTPUT rCode).

MESSAGE STRING(rCode)
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

The code compiles without errors and warning but I've got "0" in MESSAGE STRING(rCode), this sould get "6".

**Rust with mvsc with Progress**

```
Rust lib.rs
```

```
use std::os::raw::{c_int};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn HelloWorld(hello: c_int) -> c_int {
    hello * 2
}
```

```
Rust Cargo.toml
```

```
[package]
name = "DllRust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[lib]
name = "dll_rust"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
```

```
C Header
```

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int HelloWorld(int hello);
```

```
Progress
```

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.
DEFINE VARIABLE iResult AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
PROCEDURE HelloWorld EXTERNAL "C:\Users\Steee\CLionProjects\dll_rust\target\release\dll_rust.dll" CDECL:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER hello AS LONG.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER result AS LONG.
END.

RUN HelloWorld(3, OUTPUT iResult).
MESSAGE STRING(iResult)
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

EDIT: The code compiles without errors and warning now but I've got "0" in MESSAGE STRING(iResult), this sould get "6".

Comment: Your rust example fails since you have declared the procedure as DllHelloWorld but run HelloWorld

Comment: Thanks, now I have the same problem as the C++ code, 0 as result.

Comment: What happens when you replace ``output parameter`` with ``return parameter``? - see https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/DEFINE-PARAMETER-statement.html

Comment: It's work thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `define output parameter` needs to be a `define return parameter`. See [documentation](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/DEFINE-PARAMETER-statement.html).